# How to delay a live stream in stdout?

Tags: bash, audio

I have an audio stream coming to stdout which would be piped to a media player (e.g. VLC, ffplay). I want to know that is it possible to delay the audio stream by several seconds in the following manner (assumed to be in Ubuntu bash shell) :

```
<audio stream> | <stream delay program> | <media player, e.g. ffplay>
```

I want to delay the audio stream to make it more synchronize with another video stream.

Is there any program/method that could achieve this goal ?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: what's the format of the stream? raw? something else? You could create a file containing zeroes using `dd` for instance.

Then use `cat` like this:

    <audio stream> | cat zeroes.bin - | <media player, e.g. ffplay>

so when you run the command, the empty file is consumed first. But why don't you just use `sleep`?

Comment: In fact, I am using VLC for playing the audio stream. The audio is a "libfdk_aac" ffmpeg encoded, 24k (bit rate) stream. If adding "zeros" before this encoded stream, would it be correctly played by VLC ? Moreover, I don't know what you mean by "use sleep", could you elaborate more ?

Comment: I don't know about the zeros. Worth a try. By "use sleep", I mean why don't you wait before running your command?

Comment: After some search, "sleep" seems a Linux command to sleep for a certain time. However, the audio is a continuous live stream sent through the network and I could not control the creation of the stream. As a receiving side, I could only try to delay it a bit so that it would be more synchronize with another video stream.

Comment: If I could cache the audio stream for some time before sending it to the media player, then my problem would be solved. However, I don't know what program could do that for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this (python script):

```
import sys

chunk_size = 100000  # adjust according to sample rate, nb_channels, etc..

buffer2=None

while True:
    buffer1 = sys.stdin.read(chunk_size)
    if buffer2:
        sys.stdout.write(buffer2)
    buffer2 = sys.stdin.read(chunk_size)
    sys.stdout.write(buffer1)
```

would read 2 times and write only once, so it will be shifted.

Tell me if it works, it's just an attempt. I'll delete the answer if it doesn't.

Comment: The code runs OK. I could now set the chunk_size to adjust the delay time for the audio stream. Thanks.

Comment: I"m glad it works for you because I couldn't test it.